# Не создается проект PyDev(Django)

Tags: python, ubuntu, django, pydev

Установил eclipse, pydev, пытаюсь создать проект (New->Other->PyDev->Django), но почему то не создается. говорит, что у меня Django не установлен.
[Тык](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLRh1.png), 
[Тык](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1ytQ.png), 
[Путь к Django указанный в настройках PyDev](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKf9e.png),
[Создаю проект](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LG59O.png),
[Проект не создается](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4Sjq.png).
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: `Django` у вас установлен в `Python 2.7`, вы создаете проект в `Python 3.6`, может быть из-за этого?

Comment: @Jazzis возможно, но от Django отказался, не могу проверить. За ответ спасибо